# type-mismatch in a conditional operator (java)

Tags: java, javac

I don't understand why the following would NOT cause an error.

```
boolean condition = <whatever>;
return condition ? Collections.singleton("a field") : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

`Collections.singleton()` returns a `java.util.Set` which obviously is NOT the same type as `EMPTY_LIST`.

Should that really NOT cause a type-mismatch error?

Comment: Can you show more of the code? Right now it’s not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Both `Collections.singleton()` and `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` implement `Collection` (and extend `Object` for that matter). No type conversions are necessary to return the result of the ternary operator as a `Collection` or an `Object`.

The java compiler finds the most specific type that matches both parts. It gets tricky with primitive types, but only `void` is flatly forbidden. See the Java Language Specification on the [conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Answer (score 0):

#### Starting point

This code by itself is not the whole picture – it contains a "return" statement, but we do not see the method signature, and thus do not see the return type.

```
boolean condition = true;
return condition ? Collections.singleton("a field") : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

#### Method: return type Object

It would be totally fine to mix object types with a method return type of Object. For example, here's a method returning either a HashMap or an Integer. This is allowed because the method return type is Object, and both of those return types are Objects.

```
private static Object returnObject() {
    boolean condition = true;
    return condition ? new HashMap<>() : Integer.valueOf(1);
}
```

You could put the original code in a method with return type Object, and the compiler would be fine with it.

---

#### Actual object types

The type of `Collections.singleton("a field")` is `Set<String>`,
and [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) has the following definition, showing it extends Collection:

```
public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E>
```

The type of `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` is [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) which has this definition, showing it extends Collection, too:

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
```

Both the set and the list share a common parent: Collection.

---

#### Method: return type Collection

If you put the original lines of code along with a method signature having return type "Collection", that would be allowed by the compiler since both possible return values are Collections.

```
private static Collection returnCollection() {
    boolean condition = true;
    return condition ? Collections.singleton("a field") : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

---

#### Third option: Iterable

As shown above, the method can have a return type of either Collection or Object.
Additionally, you could specify the return type as
[Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html),
since Iterable is the parent of [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).